# What does "I can get behind that :)" mean when you suggest someone to compromise on an alternative option?

Tags: idioms

"How about we compromise and ... ? ;)"

Answer: "I can get behind that :)"

Comment: It means you have found a compromise the other person can [support](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-behind) or push forward. It is the second meaning of the link.

Comment: Are the wink and the smiley face part of the communication? It does make a degree of difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get behind something is to support it.  It is a metaphor that comes from the notion of being physically behind something in order to prop it up.

It doesn't specifically need to refer to a compromise. You can get behind any idea that is proposed.

> He found an investor who was willing to get behind his startup company.

See also the related terms [backup (n)](http://i.word.com/idictionary/backup) or [back up(v)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/back).

> I can back up that idea.
>   I can back that up with sources.
>   He provided the needed backup for the plan.